# Create Hexbin (honeycomb) grid using command line or Python

Tags: gdal, ogr

Qgis has this amazing [Create Grid](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_creation_tools.html#create-grid) function. Is there an alternative for python / unix command line?

I've found [Gdal_grid](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html) but it is not the same. The goal is to eventually create a hexbin heatmap.

[image]

Comment: So you're looking for a solution that doesn't involve QGIS?

Comment: Correct........

Answer (score 5):

Use GDAL with the SQLite/Spatialite dialect. Then you can utilize the ST_HexagonalGrid function that is documented in http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html.

> return a grid of hexagonal cells (having the edge length of size)
>   precisely covering the input Geometry. The returned Geometry will
>   usually be of the MultiPolygon type (a collection of Squares), but
>   will be a MultiLinestring if the optional edges_only argument is set
>   to TRUE If the optional origin argument (expected to be a Point) is
>   not specified then the (0,0) grid origin will be assumed by default.

The result is naturally collection of hexagons, not squares. Obviously manual text is copied from ST_SquareGrid function.

Usage example with ogrinfo follows. For ogrinfo there must be some bogus datasource, I used a shapefile "temp.shp".

```
ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT ST_HexagonalGrid(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 0 47, 0 50, 3 50, 3 47, 0 47 ))'),1) from test LIMIT 1" test.shp
```

The result as WKT:

```
  MULTIPOLYGON (((0.0 46.7653718043597,0.5 45.8993464005753,1.5 45.8993464005753,2.0 46.7653718043597,1.5 47.6313972081442,0.5 47.6313972081442,0.0 46.7653718043597)),((-1.5 47.6313972081442,-1.0 46.7653718043597,0.0 46.7653718043597,0.5 47.6313972081442,0.0 48.4974226119286,-1.0 48.4974226119286,-1.5 47.6313972081442)),((1.5 47.6313972081442,2.0 46.7653718043597,3.0 46.7653718043597,3.5 47.6313972081442,3.0 48.4974226119286,2.0 48.4974226119286,1.5 47.6313972081442)),((0.0 48.4974226119286,0.5 47.6313972081442,1.5 47.6313972081442,2.0 48.4974226119286,1.5 49.363448015713,0.5 49.363448015713,0.0 48.4974226119286)),((-1.5 49.363448015713,-1.0 48.4974226119286,0.0 48.4974226119286,0.5 49.363448015713,0.0 50.2294734194975,-1.0 50.2294734194975,-1.5 49.363448015713)),((1.5 49.363448015713,2.0 48.4974226119286,3.0 48.4974226119286,3.5 49.363448015713,3.0 50.2294734194975,2.0 50.2294734194975,1.5 49.363448015713)),((0.0 50.2294734194975,0.5 49.363448015713,1.5 49.363448015713,2.0 50.2294734194975,1.5 51.0954988232819,0.5 51.0954988232819,0.0 50.2294734194975)))
```

And this is how it looks. The input geometry that was to be covered by the grid is shown as a yellow rectangle.

[image]

Comment: I've also found this pretty cool blog: https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/

Comment: I've created a little python script as well: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FlIe7Oep724jRcu3MUyyL3Oav98H9f6G